# Call web API controller using Angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to Angular2. I want to call an API using Angular2 in my MVC6 project. I have tried many things (including the guide at [Angular2 calling ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234837/angular2-calling-asp-net-web-api)) without success.

I don’t know where I should start, or which files are needed.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867

Comment: What does *without success* mean here? What went wrong?

Answer (score 18):

I'd look at some of the examples on Github to see how other people have done it. There are a number of things that have to be just right for it all to work, and the errors can be nebulous until you get it up and running.

Add a Web API Controller Class to your project. Just to make sure everything is working at first, I'd suggest hard coding your HttpGet attribute to "api/values".

**ValuesController.cs.** :

```cs
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
      [HttpGet("api/values")]
      public IActionResult Get()
      {
          return new JsonResult(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
      }
```

**Startup.Cs.** You need the angular2 routes to not interfere with ASP.NET's routes. This means you need to serve the index.html to the client if there is a 404 error. The app.Use lambda accomplishes this. Notice that it is before the calls to app.UseDefaultFiles() and app.UseStaticFiles()

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        var angularRoutes = new[] {
             "/home"
         };

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && null != angularRoutes.FirstOrDefault(
                (ar) => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(ar, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                context.Request.Path = new PathString("/");
            }
            await next();
        });

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Once you have this setup, you should test your API with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/introduction) to make sure the routing is working as you want it to. If this doesn't work, it won't work in Angular. I have http://localhost:5001/ set as my *App URL* in my Visual Studio project Debug settings.

[image: postman]

If that is working correctly, move on to getting it to load with Angular 2. You'll need to use the base element just after the head tag in your html file. This tells the Angular router what the static part of the URL is:

**Index.html**

```
    <base href="/">
```

Next you'll need to create a Service in Angular2 to Get the values from your API:
**dataService.ts**

```js
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Configuration } from '../app.constants';

@Injectable()
export class DataService { 
  private actionUrl: string;
  constructor(private _http: Http, private _configuration: Configuration) {
    this.actionUrl = 'http://localhost:5001/api/values/';
}

public GetAll = (): Observable<any> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .do(x => console.log(x));
}
```

The .do operator in RxJS is very handy. It will allow you to debug that you are correctly getting the values from your API. See [Andre Staltz's blog for more details](http://staltz.com/how-to-debug-rxjs-code.html).

Finally, create a component to use the service:
**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from '../services/DataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `My Values: <ul><li *ngFor="let value of values">
        <span>{{value.id}} </span>
      </li></ul>`,
    providers: [DataService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public values: any[];
  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService
        .GetAll()
        .subscribe(data => this.values = data,
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('Get all complete'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer! However I am getting an error in the data service for app.constants. What should this app.constant file look like?

Comment: Thanks! It is just a file with constants in it. I shouldn't have included with the snippet. You should be able to delete that line without problems.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: I needed to add import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'; to get the .do logging to work!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Question: why are responses pass as arrays? public values: any[];

Answer (score 7):

This is how I did it my application (angular2 as front-end with Web API core)-

1. Create a controller using entity framework which provides all actions - GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. Refer this link in case you are new to web api and entity framework - https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html
2. Enabled CORS in Web API

[This is done to handle cross communication from localhost:3000 (angular2) to localhost:59024 (webapi)]

First, add dependency in project.json - `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",`

then enable CORS in startup.cs like this-

```cs
app.UseCors(builder => {
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
});
```

You can find more information about CORS here - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html

3.In Angular2 front-end, you can write your service component like this-

```js
@Injectable()
export class WebApiService {

    private _webApiUrl = 'http://localhost:59024/api/EmployeeMastersAPI'; 

        constructor(private _http: Http) { 

        }

    getEmployees(): Observable<{}> {
        return this._http.get(this._webApiUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <any[]> response.json())
             .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
             .catch(this.handleError)
            ;
    }

    getEmployee(id: number): Observable<IEmployee> {
        return this.getEmployees()
            .map((emp: IEmployee[]) => emp.find(p => p.EMPID === id));
    }

    addEmployeesDetails(emp) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        console.log('add emp : ' +  JSON.stringify(emp));
        this._http.post(this._webApiUrl, JSON.stringify(emp), { headers: headers }).subscribe();

    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

See if this helps.